# how to extract string from certain position

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am struggling to find a solution in string manipulation - I am trying to extract a certain part of the string element after the '=' character - say for ex.

```
 dim s as string = "/mysite/secondary.aspx?id=1005"
```

I am trying to get the string after the "=" and just to grab the 1005.  I tried indexof and split, but i am not sure where i am going wrong. Any help, please?

Here is what i did:

```
 Dim lnk As String = "/mysite/secondary.aspx?id=1005"  
 Dim id As Long = lnk.IndexOf("=")   
 Dim part As String = lnk.Substring(id + 1, 4)
```

Thanks

Comment: What about when there are more than 1 = sign in the string?  What should the behavior of the split be then?

Comment: @ ODed, pls see the above code i have tried

Comment: @ Akron, no, this is just a one '='

Comment: @Ron - in the code above change id as Long to id as Integer.  When I did that and tried your code it worked for me.  Please note that there are a lot of assumptions that could lead to errors in what you have.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following

```
Dim index = s.IndexOf("="C)
Dim value = s.Substring(index + 1)
```

This will put "1005" into `value`

Comment: "This will put '1005' into value".  That's inaccurate.  That will put 1005 into value only IF the id=1005 is the last part of the input string.

Comment: @Boo: It's accurate if there is always only one "=". I agree that your solution is probably better, but if it's guaranteed that there will always be one "=", JaredPar's solution is fine.

Comment: @Meta-Knight: It never stays just one :)

Answer (score 5):

```
Dim tUriPath As String = "/mysite/secondary.aspx?id=1005"
Dim tURI As Uri = New Uri("dummy://example.com" & tUriPath)
Dim tIdValue As String = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(tUri.Query)("id")
```

Comment: Thanks @Boo, but i am not getting this from the query string, this is getting generated from an xml

Comment: Doesnt matter.  It looks like a query string.. and that's all that matters.  Doing it this way lets the querystring be anything (eg.  id=6004&q=search&paco=manga).  Using a String.Split() method will yield undesirable results if the query portion were to change in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very simple example. Obviously it relies on very specific conditions:

```
Dim afterEquals As String = s.Split("="c)(1)
```

You would probably want something slightly more robust (checking to make sure more than one string was returned from Split, etc.).

Comment: The array index operator in VB.Net is `()` and not `[]`.

Comment: @JaredPar - Thanks. My VB.NET syntax is quite rusty.

Comment: And there's no `;` statement terminator in VB.NET.

Answer (score 0):

If you try string.Split with '=' you'll get `1005` on the first element of the array and the `/mysite/secondary.aspx?id=` on the 0th position.

But if this is just a regular URL coming from an http request.

You could possibly do `Request.QueryString("id")` and it will return `1005`;

**Borrowing code from Boo...**

```
Dim tUriPath As String = "/mysite/secondary.aspx?id=1005"
Dim tURI As Uri = New Uri("dummy://example.com" & tUriPath)
Dim tIdValue As String = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(tUri.Query)

Dim theIntYouWant as String= System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(tUri.Query)("id")
```

Comment: @ lcarus: no, this is not pulling from the querystring, if so, i would have easily grabbed it, but this is from a cms content, i am generating the list, which is an xml format !!!

Comment: @Ron: I see. If these are Urls using ParseQueryString as Boo proposed should be a lot cleaner than using Split.